# How to avoid for...in eslint issues?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have an object with some keys and values.

I initially had this loop:

```
  for(const key in commands) {
    if (commands.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = commands[key];
      // Do something else
    }
  }
```

That gave me the following eslint error:

> for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array. (no-restricted-syntax)

So I changed it to this:

```
  Object.keys(commands).forEach(key => {
    if (commands.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = commands[key];
    }
  });
```

Now, I'm getting the following error due to `hasOwnProperty`:

> Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object. (no-prototype-builtins)

How can I write a simple loop that iterates over the keys whilst avoiding eslint errors?

Comment: Don't use `Object.keys(commands).forEach(key => {`. Use `for (const key of Object.keys(commands)) {` if at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using `Object.keys`, you do not need to check `hasOwnProperty`. Object.keys produces an array of exclusively own properties. This is why the first eslint error was recommending that you use it.

For the second lint error, it's recommending that you do

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(commands, key)
```

The reason this lint rule exists is that it's possible for `commands.hasOwnProperty` to be `undefined`, if commands was created using `Object.create(null)`. In your case though, you just need to delete the check:

```
Object.keys(commands).forEach(key => {
  const value = commands[key];
  // Do something else
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can disable the eslint rule if you don't need it. As it states, `for...in` will iterate over inherited properties, so it was often used in combination with `hasOwnProperty`, but the new `Object.keys` syntax is shorter.

Second, you don't need `hasOwnProperty` if you're using `Object.keys`. It only iterates over own properties already.

Third, eslint doesn't like you using `hasOwnProperty` on an object, because it can be reassigned to be a different function. I guess it wants you to use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)` if you really need it, but I'd argue that there are plenty of cases where you know it's safe to use the shorter version. Again, you can disable the rule if you know the implications.

Comment: In every case where it's safe to use the shorter version, you pretty much also know that the object has no enumerable inherited properties, so why use it at all?

Comment: That's usually true when dealing with `for..in` loops, since it only lists enumerable properties, and if you got any enumerables on your `Object` prototype, something has gone awfully wrong. But if you need to check that an object has a certain field, `hasOwnProperty` can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` only collects the object's own properties. No need to do a `hasOwnProperty` check for it. Removing it would fix the issue of the second snippet.

If you know what you're doing/prefer `for-in` anyways, you can always add `//eslint-disable-next-line` the line before the line that's causing the errors to disable eslint warnings for that line alone.